# Is it possible to call MDM web service through iPhone code?

Tags: ios, web-services, mdm, device-management

I have to access MDM commands to my device. Without using local server can I access MDM commands through mobile service call ?

https://simplemdm.com/docs/api/?shell#introduction

From the abow link, service call is in Shell. Can I use this for iOS service call from device? How to convert the URL to swift language?

My understanding from the below link , that only through local web service device can use MDM commands. If manually call MDM commands from mobile web service to MDM server that won’t help.

Reference link:
[How to develop mobile device management application in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065620/how-to-develop-mobile-device-management-application-in-ios)

If this is the flow, anyone know how exactly the process will be ?

Comment: I actually have an MDM server setup where the iOS devices makes calls to it and the mdm server sends commands accordingly. What you need to do is setup a server and implement a `/server` and a `/checkin` route then create a configuration profile that is linked to your server. It's somewhat of a complicated process in the sense that you need a lot of knowledge to be able to set it up. For more info you can look here https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf this is mainly where I got a lot of info from. But answering your question yes it is possible.